# Pulling All Associated Rows MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to pull from a table that's been made by someone else and print it onto a web page. Issue is, that column name are stored in the rows. For instance:

```
FIELD_NAME| FIELD_VALUE
______________________
first-name| John
last-name | Smith
```

This is how I'm going about grabbing the data

```
$tableRow = '';
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE form_name = '".$nameOfForm."' ";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($tableData = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$fieldName = $tableData['field_name'];
$fieldValue = $tableData['field_value'];

//FIRST NAME
if($fieldName == 'first-name'){
$firstName = $fieldValue;
}
//LAST NAME
if($fieldName == 'last-name'){
$lastName = $fieldValue;
}

//BUILD A ROW FOR THE TABLE
$tableRow .='
<th>'.$firstName.'</th>
<th>'.$lastName.'</th>
';

}
```

it only KIND of works when I do  `$tableRow =` instead of  `$tableRow .=`
it will only show me one result, but when I do `$tableRow .=` it will only show me empty  but the correct amount of s.

How can I populate an html table with all of the results pulling from a table like this?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the whole table looks like this:

```
<table id="theTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:100px;">First Name</th>
                    <th style="width:100px;">Last Name</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="rowsGoHere">


            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and I echo the PHP result via ajax,

```
//ECHO BACK RESULTS
    $JSONData = array("true", $tableRow); 
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

and use  this to insert into table

```
var trueEncV = encodeURIComponent("true");

                $.getJSON("pullTableData.php?callback=?",
                      {
                        trueV: trueEncV
                      }, 
                      function(dataBack){
                        alert(dataBack);
                        $('#rowsGoHere').html(dataBack[1]);
                    }
                )
```

That all works fine and dandy.

Comment: your problem has noting to do with mysqli. it's basic PHP syntax  issue

Comment: BTW, I know the statement isn't prepared. No input fromanywhere is going into this query, $nameOfForm will contain a parameter set at the top of the php page.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I was trying to foreach inside of the while like while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){$rows[] = $row;
foreach($rows as $tableData){ }} But still same problem, not sure what other logic to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your updated code the `<tr>` tags are missing. Also, within `<tbody>` you should use the `<td>` tag instead of the `<th>` tag.

```
$tableRow .='
  <tr>
    <td>'.$firstName.'</td>
    <td>'.$lastName.'</td>
  </tr>
';
```

Can you try

```
echo json_encode($JSONData);
```

instead of

```
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

Comment: ohh, no. I send the databack to the HTML like this $JSONData = array("true", $tableRow); 
 echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")"; 
then I inject the data into the full table HTML with jQuery like $('#rowsGoHere').html(dataBack[1]);

Comment: Can you update your original question with the javascript code and the PHP code that sends the JSON?

Comment: try the code above; why are you returning `?([true,'html-stuff'])` instead of `[true, 'html-stuff']` ?

Comment: OK, since you mentioned it. I decided to base64_encode($tableRow) and then use the base.64 jquery plugin to decode it, i figured that maybe there was an invalid charter throwing off the JSON now works fine... but it's mostly white space. like someone enetered in 1000 blank rows

Comment: Yes, checkout my updated answer, I am quite sure it will solve the spacing issue. You didn't answer my question about the use of `?()` I am curious

Comment: Because you were awesome, and helped me get to the answer, I'm accepting this, unfortunately, i cant vote you up because I'm one reputation point too low. some a-hole voted you and I down

Comment: I voted-up your question because there was enough details to solve the issue. Glad I could help

Comment: BTW, you're right about the TR and TD tags, I'm an idiot, this worked perfect, you rock man!!! Thanks so much!